# How to get page name in JSP or JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I want to get current page name (something like "myPage") using JSP or JSTL. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get it by [`HttpServletRequest#getServletPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath%28%29).

```
${pageContext.request.servletPath}
```

You can use the [JSTL functions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html) taglib to extract the extension whenever necessary.

Comment: it gives me something like /webinf/views/myPage.jsp , can you please give me a little help how to extract the name only

Comment: Ah OK, you're using a controlling servlet which forwards to JSPs in `/WEB-INF` folder. Use `${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path']}` instead to get the servlet path of the URL as it appears in browser address bar.

Comment: i was able to do it in the following way too: request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getRequestURI().lastIndexOf("/")+1,request.getRequestURI().lastIndexOf("."));

Answer (score 0):

To get the page:

```
<% String pageName = com.kireego.utils.Utils.extractPageNameFromURLString(request.getRequestURI()); %>
```

and this helper code:

```
public static String extractPageNameFromURLString(String urlString){
        if (urlString==null) return null;
        int lastSlash = urlString.lastIndexOf("/");
        //if (lastSlash==-1) lastSlash = 0;
        String pageAndExtensions = urlString.substring(lastSlash+1);
        int lastQuestion = pageAndExtensions.lastIndexOf("?");
        if (lastQuestion==-1) lastQuestion = pageAndExtensions.length();
        String result = pageAndExtensions.substring(0,lastQuestion);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line will get you the correct JSP name, it's working also when the page includes multiple pages

```
<%= this.getClass().getSimpleName().replaceAll("_5F", "").replaceFirst("_", "") %>.jsp<BR>
```

Comment: Not working when invoked from a tag

Comment: @coterobarros need to be in the jsp body

Answer (score -3):

maybe you can get it thought javascript way, like:

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

then use string methods to get current page name.

Comment: JavaScript is neither JSP nor JSTL.