# Apply attributes to JSP pages

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

What I want to do is associate every JSP page in my project with an attribute. Lets say, I have three pages:

```
helloWorld.jsp
helloUniverse.jsp
```

and the attribute here is 'Operation'. Is there a way I could apply it to them like:

```
helloWorld.jsp -> Operation: "HelloWorld"
helloUniverse.jsp -> Operation: "HelloUniverse"
```

such that they would be available from a `ServletContextListener`:

```
public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent event) {   
    final ServletContext ctx = event.getServletContext();

    // Following is the code I wish for:
    List<Class<Servlet>> pages = ctx.getAllPages();
    for(Class<Servlet> page : pages) {
        operationMap.put(page.getName(), page.getAttribute("operation"));
    }
}
```

I know it looks extremely far-fetched.. but is something like this possible?

Comment: You could add a hidden parameter on every page which value can be filled with the answer of this question: [How to get page name in JSP or JSTL?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6008284/1065197)

Comment: The problem is that it still gets executed when the JSP is loaded. I don't want that. I need it to be present when the web application is bootstrapping.

Comment: Why do you want to build such a Map? I think that whatever you are trying to achieve you are heading to the wrong direction.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, first the static way:
Create an operation.properties and add all operation-values line-for-line.

```
  HelloWorld=helloWorld.jsp
  HelloUniverse=helloUniverse.jsp
```

Comment: This is not a good solution, it will be very hard to maintain when creating new pages, changing names and deleting.

Answer (score -1):

This is just a theory but:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>helloWorldJsp</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/helloWorld.jsp</jsp-file>
<init-param>
<param-name>operation</param-name>
<param-value>HelloWorld</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>helloUniverseJsp</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/helloUniverse.jsp</jsp-file>
<init-param>
<param-name>operation</param-name>
<param-value>helloUniverse</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
```

you can actually map your jsp's as servlets (in the end they are servlets, right?) assign the init parameters there and then read them at bootstrap, i dont know if this will suffice but it might be what you need.
In the downside is that you have to redeclare all your jsp's inside the web.xml but hey its better than static things.

If you dont hold any love to static variables you can also have a resource file and read it at bootstrap and maintain the file along with the jsp's that might also work.

Comment: How's this supposed to be maintained when creating, changing names or deleting pages? It will be a hell of work.