# How can I print page info in jsp files?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to print or get the jsp page info(Copyright 2023 by sean) but don't know how to do. Here is my jsp code script

```
<%@ page info="Copyright 2023 by sean" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>directive1.jsp</title>
    <h1>Directive Example1</h1>
</head>
<body>
<%=this.getServletInfo()%>
</body>
</html>
```

As my textbook says, first I put `<%=this.getServletInfo()%>` in body, and there comes error
"Cannot resolve method 'getServletInfo' in 'JspClass'"
I use Intellij ultimate and java maven project. Since getServletInfo cannot be resolved, I think I have to put other dependencies in pom.xml. If so, what do I have to add?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demojsp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demojsp</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.9.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I tried to type ${pageContext.request.servletPath} according to this article[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007678/how-to-get-page-name-in-jsp-or-jstl) but, it prints path not info.

Comment: Can you try adding servlet dependency in pom.xml and rebuild verify 
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: @AnandDwivedi Thank you for reply! I tried, still doesn't work. Previously, I added jakarta.servlet because I use tomcat11.

Comment: try like below ? also can you see if your IDE is showing getServletInfo method . also clean install or build app to verify 

<%@page info="Copyright 2023 by sean" %>

<%=getServletInfo()%>

Comment: @AnandDwivedi My snippet doesn't show getServletInfo method. but I can find a String type getServletInfo() in Servlet Interface and method in GenericServlet Class (jakarta.servlet). <%=getServletInfo()%> doesn't works too.